# Android: загрузка данных в ListView через AsyncTask

Tags: getview, android, listview, java, android-asynctask

Приветствую всех, столкнулся с некоторой проблемой, поиски по которой привели меня в тупик. 
Создаю собственный `Adapter` для связи с `ListView`, но так как изображения большого размера решил загрузить их в отдельном потоке

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{ 
 private final Context context; 
 private final String[] values; 
 private final int[] imgid; 
 LayoutInflater inflater; 
 public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values, int[] val2)  
 { 
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values); 
    this.context = context; 
    this.values = values; 
    this.imgid = val2; 
    inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater(); 
 }

static class ViewHolder  
{ 
    public ImageView imageView; 
    public TextView textView; 
    public int imageId; 
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{                        
     ViewHolder holder = null; 
     if (convertView == null)  
     { 
     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null); 
     holder = new ViewHolder(); 
     holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ac_s_item_1_tv_1); 
     holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ac_s_item_1_iv_1); 
     holder.position = position; 
     holder.imageId = imgid[position]; 
     convertView.setTag(holder); 
      } 
      else  
      { 
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
      } 
      holder.textView.setText(values[position]);

      new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() 
      { 
               ViewHolder v;         
     @Override 
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)  
     { 
         if (v.position == position) 
           { 
                       super.onPostExecute(result); 
                v.imageView.setImageBitmap(result); 
            } 
    }

    @Override 
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... parameter)  
    { 
           v = parameter[0]; 
           Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), v.imageId); 
            return bm; 
     } 
  }.execute(holder);

return convertView; 
}
```

}

При запуске приложения, первые элементы `ListView` отображаются корректно, но при прокрутке изображения начинают дублироваться, то есть первый элемент который был скрыт, имеет то же изображение что и первый элемент `ListView`. Надеюсь я доходчиво объяснил проблему.
Во входных параметрах адаптера массив строк и массив идентификаторов изображений.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Answer (score 1):

```
if (v.position == position)
```

Правую переменную надо передать внутрь `AsynсTask` и сохранить, а потом сравнивать. Иначе получается что всегда будут сравниваться одни и те же числа.

Comment: Не очень понимаю как это сделать если во вхоящих параметрах AsynсTask ViewHolder

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, но не уверен что моя реализация удачна

Comment: На самом деле если будет много больших картинок и быстрый скролл списка, то приложение вылетит с OOM(out of memory). Чтобы этого не было надо написать свой менеджер изображений, который будет хранить каждую декодированную Bitmap в LruCache. Или же воспользоватся существующими решениями: Picasso, Volley, UIL. Статья от google, про загрузку больших изображений.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
https://github.com/square/picasso
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Готовые решения коннечно хорошо, но не особо способствуют развитию новичка) Спасибо в общем)

Comment: Ну там исходники есть, можно их почитать и сделать своё :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать вместо AsyncTask библиотеку UniversalImageLoader, в нем метод displayImage, который принимает в параметры ImageView и URL